# Loading an image

Tags: php, html

```
echo '<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Character Name</th>
    <th>Ban Reason</th>
    <th>Ban Length</th>
    <th>Proof</th>
    <th>Banned On</th>
  </tr>';

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<tr>
    <td><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$row['steamId'].'">'.$row['charactername'].'</a></td>
    <td>'.$row['banMessage'].'</td>
    <td>'.convertToHumanReadableTime($row['banDuration']).'</td>
    <td>'<img src='".$row['spy']."' />;'</td>
    <td>'.date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['banTime'])).'</td>
  </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

the Image loading isn't working cause idk it should get the link ending on .jpg inside the db

Comment: <td>'<img src='".$row['spy']."' />;'</td>
get rid of that single quote between the td and the img

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your quotes.

Change

```
echo '<tr>
<td><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$row['steamId'].'">'.$row['charactername'].'</a></td>
<td>'.$row['banMessage'].'</td>
<td>'.convertToHumanReadableTime($row['banDuration']).'</td>
<td>'<img src='".$row['spy']."' />;'</td>
<td>'.date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['banTime'])).'</td></tr>';
```

To

```
echo '<tr>
<td><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$row['steamId'].'">'.$row['charactername'].'</a></td>
<td>'.$row['banMessage'].'</td>
<td>'.convertToHumanReadableTime($row['banDuration']).'</td>
<td><img src="'.$row['spy'].'" />;</td>
<td>'.date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['banTime'])).'</td></tr>';
```